# Using PDO's traversable interface with a different fetch_style

Tags: php, pdo

PDO allows `foreach` to be performed directly on the statement object without using either `fetch` or `fetchAll` since it implements the [Traversable interface](http://php.net/traversable).

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM example');
foreach($stmt as $row){
    //...
}
```

I have configured my PDO object to return objects by default using `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`.  If I wish to return arrays instead of objects, can the traversable interface approach use a different fetch_style, or will one need to explicitly use `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can still pass fetch_mode as an argument to query method

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM example', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```